# Why is my iterator being advanced again?

Tags: node.js, promise, generator, stripe-payments, ecmascript-6

I have the following program - I use genny.js to handle the asynchronous flow control - I have tried the same with suspend.js - similar error.

I am using the Stripe nodejs API.

My iterator function seems to be called twice - which is causing an error - and I don't understand why it gets called twice. It must be a simple mind trick that I am not seeing.

```
var genny = require('genny')
genny.longStackSupport = true

var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_live_....")

fetchCharges = genny.fn(function* (d) {
  console.log("Before fetchCharges")
  var charges = yield fetchList(d())
  console.log("After fetchCharges - found ", charges.length)
  return true
})

fetchList = genny.fn(function* (done) {
  console.log("before fetchList")
  var results = yield stripe.charges.list({}, done())
  console.log("after fetchList")
  return results.data
})

genny.run(function* (resume) {
  console.log('before run')
  yield fetchCharges(resume())
  console.log('after run')
})
```

The console output is:

```
> node --harmony genny.js

before run
Before fetchCharges
before fetchList
after fetchList
After fetchCharges - found  10
after run
/Volumes/dev/ingest/node_modules/genny/index.js:50
        else throw e; 
                   ^
Error: callback already called
    at resume (/Volumes/dev/ingest/node_modules/genny/index.js:154:39)
    at throwAt (/Volumes/dev/ingest/node_modules/genny/index.js:49:30)
    at resume (/Volumes/dev/ingest/node_modules/genny/index.js:153:28)
    at tryProcessPending (/Volumes/dev/ingest/node_modules/genny/index.js:41:28)
    at resume (/Volumes/dev/ingest/node_modules/genny/index.js:164:17)
    at null._onTimeout (/Volumes/dev/ingest/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:87:34)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
From generator:
    at /Volumes/dev/ingest/genny.js:22:26
```

Now, if I replace fetchList with the following function it works fine:

```
fetchList = genny.fn(function* (done) {
  console.log('before doTimeout')
  console.log('1sec break ...')
  yield setTimeout(done(), 1000);
  console.log('after doTimeout')
  return []
})
```

The console output is:

```
> node --harmony genny.js

before run
Before fetchCharges
before doTimeout
1sec break ...
after doTimeout
After fetchCharges - found  0
after run
```

To further illustrate the fact that the itertor's next() method gets called twice - I have another (non-working) version of the program.

```
var genny = require('genny')
genny.longStackSupport = true

var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_live_...")

fetchCharges = genny.fn(function* (d) {
  console.log("Before fetchCharges")
  var charges = yield fetchList(function(err, cb) {
    console.log("callback")
  })
  console.log("After fetchCharges - found ", charges.length)
  return true
})

fetchList = genny.fn(function* (done) {
  console.log("before fetchList")
  var results = yield stripe.charges.list({}, done())
  console.log("after fetchList")
  return results.data
})

genny.run(function* (resume) {
  console.log('before run')
  yield fetchCharges(resume())
  console.log('after run')
})
```

And it's console output is here:

```
> node --harmony genny.js

before run
Before fetchCharges
before fetchList
after fetchList
callback
callback
```

It's weird - and I don't get it. Can somebody cleverer than me please explain.

**UPDATE**

I have changed the code to call the stripe methods without a callback or 
the iterator resume function. And now it works. BUT - curiously - look at the console at the "results". I don't get why. So now it doesn't call the fetchList iterator's next() function "a second time" - but I don't see where it even gets called once!?

```
var results = yield stripe.charges.list()
```

Here's the updated complete program.

```
var genny = require('genny')
genny.longStackSupport = true

var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_live_i6TrEk5lSRM1CmbSZZPsQzKc")

fetchCharges = genny.fn(function* (d) {
  console.log("  fetchCharges {")
  var charges = yield fetchList(d())
  console.log("  } fetchCharges - found ", charges.length)
  return true
})

fetchList = genny.fn(function* (done) {
  console.log("    fetchList {")
  var results = yield stripe.charges.list({}, function(err, results) {
    console.log("results ")
  })
  console.log("    } fetchList")
  return results.data
})

genny.run(function* (resume) {
  console.log('Before run {')
  yield fetchCharges(resume())
  console.log('} after run')
})
```

This returns

```
> node --harmony genny.js

Before run {
  fetchCharges {
    fetchList {
    } fetchList
  } fetchCharges - found  10
} after run
results
```

Comment: Are you sure that `stripe.charges.list` doesn't call its callback multiple times?

Comment: Check if the results from `yield stripe.charges.list(...)` actually make sense (that is, if they actually have a `data` array).

Comment: I've updated the question with code where I don't even provide a callback or resume() function to the stripe call - and now it works. I can't make sense of it though. I did briefly substitute the resume() function I pass in as a callback to the stripe call with a callback function and it was only called once (perhaps because I didn't advance the iterator after that?)

Comment: Well, what does `stripe.charges.list(…)` return? Please log it (before you `yield` it)

Comment: If I pass in a callback into the stripe call - like you're supposed to - it returns the json result from stripe as expected. The callback also only get called once.

Comment: @Bergi - I've updated the code and the console update. Very strange output sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing stems from a mix of two approaches for asynchrony.

The [stripe API docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe#api-overview) mentions

> Every resource method accepts an optional callback as the last argument.
>   Additionally, every resource method returns a promise.

However, both [genny](https://github.com/spion/genny#genny) and [suspend](https://github.com/jmar777/suspend#suspend) do

> work seamlessly with Node callback conventions *and* promises

And here lies your mistake: in the line

```
var results = yield stripe.charges.list({}, done())
```

you do implicitly use **both** at the same time. The `done()` does create a callback which is passed to stripe, but that call also produces a promise which is yielded, and genny/suspend register another callback on it. This leads to the `Error: callback already called` you are observing.

You may choose how you want to fix the problem:

- don't yield the promise

  ```
  var results = yield void stripe.charges.list({}, done())
  //                  ^^^^
  ```
- don't pass a callback

  ```
  var results = yield stripe.charges.list({})
  ```

(I'd recommend the latter)

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks so much for your detailed answer. I can carry on with my life now.